Angular acceleration of a pulley

This is the way I solved but the answer seems to be different.
Torque = $Iα$
Torque = $Mgr-\dfrac{Mgr}{2} = \dfrac{Mgr}{2}$
$\dfrac{3}{4}Mr^2 = \dfrac{Mgr}{2}$
Cancelling things give, $α = \dfrac{2g}{3r}$ which is wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated!!


Your approach to the question is incorrect. You have simply considered tension in both strings same and you also ignored the effect of acceleration of both the blocks. This has resulted into an inaccurate answer. Follow the below steps and I hope it will help you!
You need to assume the tension in both strings different and as $T_1$ and $T_2$. Take the acceleration of one of the blocks $a_1$ in downwards direction and that of other as $a_2$ in upwards direction (which will be because we are assuming $T_1$ produces greater torque than $T_2$ and thus the net movement will be clockwise. Assume the angular acceleration as $\alpha$.
Thus, the equations can be written as follows:
$$T_2 - Mg = M_a \\ 2Mg - T_1 = Ma_1 \\ \text{Net torque} = I\alpha.$$
Thus,
$$T_2 R - T_1 R = I\alpha.$$
Also, the acceleration along the points on the string at point of contact due to the angular acceleration must be same to the linear acceleration since all the points are moving with acceleration $a_1$ and $a_2$.
Thus,
$$a_1 = \alpha r \\ a_2 = \frac{\alpha r}{2}.$$
Now, solving these equations by substituting $a_1$ and $a_2$ and finding $T_1$ and $T_2$ and substituting $T_1$ and $T_2$ in the $I\alpha$ equation, you will get,
$$Mr(g-\alpha R) - \frac{Mr}{2}\left(g+\frac{\alpha r}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{4} Mr^2 \alpha.$$
On solving this,
$$\alpha = \frac{g}{4r}.$$
Hope this helps!
